# Tomcat Server Won't Work With Any Port Number

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server

I am getting the error "Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start" when I attempt to open the server in Eclipse.  I've tried turning the computer on and off, reinstalling Tomcat, and repeatedly changing the server port values.  Does anyone recognize anything in the following error code that might help me to figure out why the heck I can't get my server to work.

```
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance 

in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files  
(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:
\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java 
/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE 
Components\TCS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:
\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:
\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft 
SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn
\;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Eclipse for Java EE 
Developers;;.

Nov 29, 2014 8:16:48 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init

SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:549)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:182)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:703)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:843)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
atsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)

apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServe
 rSocketFactory.java:50)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
... 12 more

Nov 29, 2014 8:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initialize
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException:   
Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:703)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:843)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.
java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

Nov 29, 2014 8:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1199 ms
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.43
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:49 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:549)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:565)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:209)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1196)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
atsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
atorg.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServer
SocketFactory.java:50)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
... 12 more

Nov 29, 2014 8:16:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
SEVERE: Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed:    
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1203)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.

DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)


Nov 29, 2014 8:16:49 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: Port busy 8009 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:49 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
SEVERE: Can't find free port 8009 8009
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:49 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=6/38  config=null
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1293 ms
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)

at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:404)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:676)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:628)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
atsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Nov 29, 2014 8:16:49 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Nov 29, 2014 8:16:50 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is an application (or your own project) that is using port 8080. `Tomcat` uses by default that port to deploy applications. You can try these solutions:

1. You can use the `netstat` command line tool as @Dulith De Cozta says, or if you prefer the graphical tool you can use`TCP View`, find port 8080 and **"End process..."**.

[image]

2. Change the port of **tomcat editor** on **eclipse**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
Tomcat: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
```

suggests that the port 8080 is already in use.
You may either:

Try searching for that process and stop it OR
Make your tomcat to run on different (free) port

**Searching for that process and stop it procedure:**

If you running on windows you can use, `netstat -aon` executed in the command prompt. For linux, `netstat -tulpn | grep 8080`. Once this is executed you will get a list of processes running on the 8080 port as you get `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080` exception.

Now execute this command in the linux terminal : `kill -9 {process pid}`. In windows, `taskkill /f /pid {pid}`
PID stands for the process ID. Now that process is killed. Try running Tomcat again. It will work now.

**Tomcat to run on different (free) port**
Please refer to this article. It well explained the procedure of changing the port number.
http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/